# Why is Solr throwing exceptions on unfound text files after insttalling Apache Solr Multilingual config files?

Tags: i18n-l10n, search

I have used Apache Solr Multilingual to generate Solr config files; however after installing these files Solr throws many exceptions of the form :

`Can't find resource '<text_file_name>_<lang>.txt'`

For example

`Can't find resource ' mapping-ISOLatin1Accent_fr.txt'`

Is the configuration of such files not the purpose of the Apache Solr Multilingual module ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the configuration of such files not the purpose of the Apache Solr Multilingual module ?

Seems the answer is 'no'.  I manually created 6 text files per language in my solr config and solr started without complaint.

Each language needs each of these text files:

```
compoundwords_<lang>.txt
mapping-FoldToASCII_<lang>.txt
mapping-ISOLatin1Accent_<lang>.txt
protwords_<lang>.txt
stopwords_<lang>.txt
synonyms_<lang>.txt
```

where 'lang' is the Drupal language code which can be confirmed by looking over the schema.xml kicked out by Solr Multilingual Module . for example: 'en', 'es', 'de' ...

I copied the contents of each of said files from the Solr Multilingual Module config. forms